# Forward traffic on specific address to external host with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables

I'd to forward all TCP traffic on port 25565 connected through the IP of `xx.xx.xx.xx` externally to `yy.yy.yy.yy` on port 25565.

Essentially,

```
xx.xx.xx.xx:25565 --> yy.yy.yy.yy:25565
```

It can't, however, forward connections from any IP- it must be from `xx.xx.xx.xx.`